# How to dismiss Heads-up Notifications quickly without clearing them from notification bar?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notifications

In Lollipop, apps are able to use Heads-up Notifications over other apps. Sometimes it is useful and sometimes it pisses me off (especially during gaming).

I can always swipe them away, but it clears them from notification bar which I don't want. How to dismiss those notification quickly without clearing them from notification bar?

If the behavior is dependent on the app, the notification creator app involved here is Todoist.

Comment: AFAIK it is possible to swipe-up those notifications to dismiss them without removing them. Depending on the app, swiping to the side may work (at least for Google Apps it works).

Comment: @Why What is *Blocking Mode*? How to access it?

Comment: The swipe-up feature that GiantTree mentioned is implemented on Lollipop 5.1, unfortunately. AFAIK, there's no way to do that before that version, and I believe it's not dependent to the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In stock Android 5.0 Lollipop, it's not possible to dismiss the heads-up notification without clearing them from the notification bar (I had that problem when using fullscreen apps too). AFAIK, this is related to Android framework, and is impossible to be modified by apps (even for Google apps).

However, this is "fixed" in Android 5.1. You can swipe up the heads-up, dismissing the heads-up only, and the notification will still be there on the notification bar.

From [Android Police - [Android 5.1 Feature Spotlight] You Can Now Swipe Up To Dismiss Heads Up Notifications Instead Of Getting Rid Of Them Permanently](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/02/21/android-5-1-feature-spotlight-can-now-swipe-dismiss-heads-notifications-instead-getting-rid-permanently/),

> With this feature addition to Android 5.1, you can swipe up to get it out of your way without losing it entirely.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has been irritating me so much! I wish I could get rid of them entirely.