# How to disable heads up notifications and immersive mode?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notifications, immersive-mode

I recommended purchasing android smart phone (moto e 2015 with android 5.0.2) to a non-technical savy friend of mine and he did. Few UI aspects of android always annoy newcomers.

One such is incoming call arriving as heads-up notification. I want to disable heads-up notifications for incoming calls or maybe system-wide. Is there any way to do so. The device is not rooted and runs stock android 5.0.2. I already tried this [HeadsOff](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jamworks.noheadsup) app and it doesn't allow me to select Phone app in free mode.

Also the device has on-screen navigation buttons alone, like in nexus devices. Whenever any app, say a game takes immersive mode the navbar is hidden and the user feels crazy. Is there any way to disable immersive mode for any or all apps? The device is not rooted and runs stock android 5.0.2.

Comment: For the problem with immersive mode, you can try the apps noted [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/129729/enable-software-menu-without-virtual-keys/129733#comment161703_129758). They would provide an alternative way of navigating the device, independent of navigation bar. Alternatively, you can use Tasker to create a scene of size equivalent to said bar and show it only when that game is active. Immersive mode won't be able to mess with it. It's quite easy to make too.

Comment: @Firelord Floating Toucher is close to what I need. In immersive mode, Floating Toucher presents its regular dot in the screen and when it is tapped, it shows its menu along with the navbar. Isn't Tasker a paid app? Could you link to it, there are too many with the name?

Comment: There's a 7-day full trial for Tasker. http://tasker.dinglisch.net/download.html

Answer (score 1):

For the notification issue, try running `settings put global heads_up_enabled 0` from `adb shell`.

For immersive mode: If the device is rooted you could use the Xposed mode [App Settings](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-app-settings-v1-9-2014-05-14-t2437377).  It has a Fullscreen setting where you can force disable fullscreen for apps.

Comment: CM must have changed something I suppose. [Clear popup/push notification of an app without getting it removed from Notification drawer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/124330)

Comment: The `adb shell settings put global heads_up_notifications_enabled 0` worked. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Oh, no app needed for HeadsOff – didn't know that! In case of being afraid of ADB, see my list for [Notification Settings](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_settings#group_543), has several candidates for that.

Comment: @Matthew Read  The device is not rooted, I guess immersive mode cannot be turned off. Maybe app developers need to provide such option.