# Annoying notification bar

Tags: notifications, notification-bar, notification-icons

Ever since I updated to the newest version on my S5 a month ago I've been annoyed by the new notification bar, the bar used to be out of the way and was only as big as the black bar up top. The new bar is annoyingly big, it's always popping up over text I'm trying to read and I keep accidentally pressing the notification bar when I'm trying to navigate my phone. Is there a way to go back to the old bar?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot so we can see it more clearly? My best guess is that you could downgrade to the earlier android version / firmware but if I remember correctly Samsung does not allow this in most cases. You could install a custom rom though to overcome the issue most likely

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are disturbed with Heads Up (new feature) notifications.
It will show a pop up notification on your screen. You can turn it off by Upgrading to any custom ROM or you can use [HeadsOff](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jamworks.noheadsup) app.
Which looks like a workaround for turn off Heads Up notifications.
I haven't tried this yet. But please take a look.

Answer (score -1):

What you're talking about sounds like "Heads Up". This is a new Android feature that shows notifications easier. You can't turn this off unless you have Android M. But you shouldn't have Android M because the S5 doesn't get this update. The only other option is to run a custom ROM such as cyanogenmod.

Comment: In truth, you could also turn it off if running a custom firmware such as CyanogenMod, if the OP wishes to give it a try.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman I could add that to my answer.

Comment: My answer is applicable on stock Lollipop as well: [Clear popup/push notification of an app without getting it removed from Notification drawer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/124330)